# Unity scaling iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, iphone-6-plus

I am building a 2D game in Unity and wondered if anyone could provide some insight into how it renders on the iPhone 6 plus.

I assumed if I didn't add the Launch Screen file Xcode would build it at iPhone 5 resolution as it does with all other apps, however this doesn't seem to be the case. I have tested the game against all other iOS screen devices (both iPhone and iPad) and the game maintains perfect scale, but as soon as I run it on a 6 plus all of the assets seem to scale down (appear much smaller).

My question is, is there a way to stop this from happening, either in the editor(s) or in code? My first thought was to increase the game scale but not sure this is the best way to go. I am using unity 4.6 RC1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you use "unity3d" tag instead of "unity" tag, they are 2 different things, people will downvote you because of it

Comment: If you're using Unity 4.6's new UI, try adding a CanvasScaler component to the Canvas: http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html